# Почему не работает вывод нод в xml

Tags: xml, xslt

**Имеется xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='transform.xsl'?>
<EagleML eaglemlVersion="2-0" actualBuild="1" eaglemlType="accountTransactionMessage" xmlns="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0">
<header>
    <batchIdentifier>
        <batchId>ADX_A.20111111</batchId>
        <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
        <totalCount>4</totalCount>
    </batchIdentifier>
    <sentBy>MYFIRM</sentBy>
    <creationTimestamp>2012-12-14T22:33:50.816-06:00</creationTimestamp>
</header>
<validation validationScheme="MYFIRM" xmlns="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0">MYFIRM</validation>
<party id="MYFIRM" xmlns="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0">
    <partyId>MYFIRM</partyId>
    <partyName>MYFIRM Investments</partyName>
</party>
<accountTransaction>
    <header>
        <identifier id="MYFIRM">
            <transactionId transactionIdScheme="MYFIRM">MYFIRM</transactionId>
        </identifier>
    </header>
    <rating>
        <sourceName>SOURCE1</sourceName>
        <updateSource>ADMIN</updateSource>
        <updateDate>2012-12-16</updateDate>
        <ratingDataModel>
            <alphaRating>2</alphaRating>
            <submittedBy>l5mbeatt</submittedBy>
            <submittedDate>2012-12-14T15:57:29-06:00</submittedDate>
            <ratingCode>RV_2</ratingCode>
            <ratingTypeIndicator/>
            <spValue>BT_TEXT</spValue>
        </ratingDataModel>
    </rating>
</accountTransaction>
<accountTransaction>
    <header>
        <identifier id="MYFIRM">
            <transactionId transactionIdScheme="MYFIRM">MYFIRM</transactionId>
        </identifier>
    </header>
    <rating>
        <sourceName>SOURCE1</sourceName>
        <updateSource>ADMIN</updateSource>
        <updateDate>2012-12-12</updateDate>
        <ratingDataModel>
            <alphaRating>45</alphaRating>
            <submittedBy>l5mbeatt</submittedBy>
            <submittedDate>2012-12-14T15:57:29-06:00</submittedDate>
            <ratingCode>TH_45</ratingCode>
            <ratingTypeIndicator/>
            <spValue>TH_45</spValue>
        </ratingDataModel>
    </rating>
</accountTransaction>
<accountTransaction>
    <header>
        <identifier id="MYFIRM">
            <transactionId transactionIdScheme="MYFIRM">MYFIRM</transactionId>
        </identifier>
    </header>
    <rating>
        <sourceName>SOURCE1</sourceName>
        <updateSource>ADMIN</updateSource>
        <updateDate>2012-12-12</updateDate>
        <ratingDataModel>
            <alphaRating>CONCERN</alphaRating>
            <submittedBy>l5bprice</submittedBy>
            <submittedDate>2012-12-14T15:43:59-06:00</submittedDate>
            <ratingCode>BT_TEXT</ratingCode>
            <ratingTypeIndicator>WATCHLIST</ratingTypeIndicator>
            <spValue>BT_TEXT</spValue>
            <ratingDate1>2012-12-14</ratingDate1>
        </ratingDataModel>
    </rating>
</accountTransaction>
<accountTransaction>
    <header>
        <identifier id="MYFIRM">
            <transactionId transactionIdScheme="MYFIRM">MYFIRM</transactionId>
        </identifier>
    </header>
    <rating>
        <sourceName>SOURCE1</sourceName>
        <updateSource>ADMIN</updateSource>
        <updateDate>2012</updateDate>
        <ratingDataModel>
            <alphaRating>CONCERN</alphaRating>
            <submittedBy>nfallon</submittedBy>
            <submittedDate>2012-12-14T16:05:25-06:00</submittedDate>
            <ratingCode>BT_TEXT</ratingCode>
            <ratingTypeIndicator>WATCHLIST</ratingTypeIndicator>
            <spValue>BT_TEXT</spValue>
            <ratingDate1>2012-12-14</ratingDate1>
        </ratingDataModel>
    </rating>
</accountTransaction>
</EagleML>
```

**Пишу к нему xslt файл для трансформации:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="//accountTransaction"> 
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Задача стоит вывести по фильтру. Но не работает даже обычный вывод любого элемента,хотя с другим xml данная конструкция вполне работоспособна. Работает только вывод всех элементов - **//*** .

Comment: Нужно указывать пространство имен.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Разве не указано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В представленном xml используется пространство имён по умолчанию:

```
xmlns="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0"
```

Значит, при обращении к нему нужно указывать это пространство имён.

В xslt это делается так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:eag="http://www.eagleinvsys.com/2011/EagleML-2-0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//eag:accountTransaction">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Добавляем все необходимые пространства имён, назначаем им префиксы (я взял `eag` от `eagle`; можно выбрать что угодно). Далее добавляем этот префикс в xpath.